# Combine NavigationTitle and Navigation Back Button SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, ios-navigationview

I have an app that has a navigationLink from one view to another, but when the NavLink moves to the second view, the NavigationTitle of that view is pushed, down, it's not inline. Is there any way to combine the toolbar and the title? I put my code below.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("My Stuff")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                        NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView(), label: {
                            Image(systemName: "gear")
                                .font(.system(size: 25))
                                .navigationTitle("My Stuff")
                        })
                        
                        
                      
                    }
                    
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the second view:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Settings View")
                    .navigationTitle("Settings")
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A photo below of what is happening:[image: photo of problem]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should show your code. It sounds like you may be duplicating `NavigationView`. Or, you're looking for https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbartitledisplaymode(_:), but I'm unclear of which (or both).

Comment: Thank you; I put in my code. I tried changing the `navigationBarTitleDisplayMode` to .inline, but it still displays below the back button.

Comment: My suspicion was correct -- you have multiple `NavigationView`s. Get rid of the one in `SettingsView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jnpdx solved this... the solution was that I had an extra `NavigationView` in my SettingsView. I only needed one `NavigationView`.