# The "Back" button messes up the view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have this problem while working with SwiftUI.
So basically, when I press on the navigation link, it opens the screen like this:[image: Picture 1]

and because of this, the whole thing below that is pushed lower.
And then, when I press to the navigation link from this screen, the result is this:

[image: Picture 2]

so it goes even lower and creates the second "back" button.

How do I get rid of this "padding" created by the "back" button?

The way I did the navigations:

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Text("Hi")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are certainly using repeated/ nested `NavigationView` lines and not hiding the navigation title. But without a piece a code, it's hard to say more. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you improve your question.

Comment: Make sure there is only one NavigationView sitting at the bottom of the view hierarchy

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71774468/combine-navigationtitle-and-navigation-back-button-swiftui

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the community can both reproduce your code and suggest improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you have duplicate `NavigationViews`. There are two ways to solve this:

1. When you call the next view in your `NavigationLink`, set `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)`. This will disappear the extra back button.
2. A simpler way; just delete the `NavigationView` in your second view (the linked one). That will prevent duplicate back buttons.

Comment: thank you so much! your comments and your answer helped me. i'm just a bit confused with the transportation between the screens, just switched to swiftui after uikit. thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help.